# Laravel 5.2.45 Route object not found

Tags: laravel, routes

I am new to laravel.
I am developing a SPA(singlepage web application) for an institute and I need to add an admin login panel to change the content (CMS). 
The SPA can view by `sitename.com` but the admin panel only can view for url `sitename.com/admin`. Then the admin had to enter username and password and login.
When I enter the user name and password it gives an **"Object Not Found"** Error 404.[Here is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/koKBW.png)

Note : Previously I've done one project on Laravel same version like this but this kind of error didn't occurs.

My form.blade syntax

```
<form action="{{ route('signIn') }}">
```

Then my route.php file

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/admin', function () {
    return view('admin');
});

Route::get('/cms',[
    'uses'=>'UserController@getCms',
    'as'=>'cms'
]);

Route::post('/signIn',[
    'uses'=>'UserController@postSignIn',
    'as'=>'signIn'
]);
```

my UserController.php

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function postSignIn(Request $request)
    {
        if(\Auth::attempt(['email'=>$request['email'],'password'=>$request['password']])){
            return redirect()->route('cms');
        }
        return redirect()->back();
    }
    public function getCms(){
        return view('cms');
    }
}
```

Comment: Which route contains the signin form? Also run `php artisan route:list` and share the result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't tell the form you're posting to `POST` method. But your route is `POST`.

Try this:

```
<form action="{{ route('signIn') }}" method="POST">
```